# I specified the birthdate(yyyy-MM-dd) field as a Date type, but an error occurs in the test code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

Requests and responses are sent and received with Postman, but the test code fails as follows.
[error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4il7.png)
[error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvFOs.png)

```
2023-03-17 01:10:44.796 DEBUG 1388 --- [    Test worker] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-03-17 01:10:44.920  WARN 1388 --- [    Test worker] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM': Cannot parse date "Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd")); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM': Cannot parse date "Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 36] (through reference chain: com.mainproject.udog_server.api.dto.DogDto$Post["dogBirthDate"])]
2023-03-17 01:10:44.920 DEBUG 1388 --- [    Test worker] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /my-dogs
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"124"]
             Body = {"dogName":"럭키","dogBirthDate":"Jan 1, 1970, 9:00:02 AM","dogSpecies":"기타","dogWeight":10,"dogDescription":"없음"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.mainproject.udog_server.api.controller.DogController
           Method = com.mainproject.udog_server.api.controller.DogController#postDog(Post, Principal)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<201> but was:<400>
Expected :201
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214)
    at com.mainproject.udog_server.restdocs.dog.DogControllerRestDocsTest.postDogTest(DogControllerRestDocsTest.java:109)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

My test code is here

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
public class DogControllerRestDocsTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private DogService dogService;

    @MockBean
    private MemberService memberService;
    @MockBean
    private DogMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Test
    void postDogTest() throws Exception {
        //given

        DogDto.Post post = new DogDto.Post("럭키", new Date(2022-01-01), Dog.DogSpecies.기타, 10, "없음");
        String content = gson.toJson(post);

        Member mockMember = new Member();
        mockMember.setMemberId(1L);

        Principal principal = () -> "test@test.com";
        given(memberService.findLoginMemberByEmail(Mockito.anyString())).willReturn(mockMember);

        given(mapper.dogPostDtoToDog(Mockito.any(DogDto.Post.class))).willReturn(new Dog());

        given(dogService.createDog(Mockito.any(Dog.class))).willReturn(new Dog());

        DogDto.Response responseDto = new DogDto.Response(1L,"럭키",  "2022-01-01", Dog.DogSpecies.기타, 10, "없음");

        given(mapper.dogToDogResponse(Mockito.any(Dog.class))).willReturn(responseDto);

        //when
        ResultActions actions =
                mockMvc.perform(
                        post("/my-dogs")
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(content)
                                .with(user("test@test.com"))
                                .principal(principal)
                );

        //then
        actions
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", is(startsWith("/my-dogs"))))
                .andDo(document(
                        "post-dog",
                        getRequestPreProcessor(),
                        getResponsePreProcessor(),
                        requestFields(
                                List.of(
                                        fieldWithPath("dogName").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("강아지 이름"),
                                        fieldWithPath("dogBirthDate").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("강아지 생일"),
                                        fieldWithPath("dogSpecies").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("강아지 품종"),
                                        fieldWithPath("dogWeight").type(JsonFieldType.NUMBER).description("강아지 몸무게"),
                                        fieldWithPath("dogDescription").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("특이사항")
                                )
                        ),
                        responseHeaders(
                                headerWithName(HttpHeaders.LOCATION).description("Location header. 등록된 리소스의  URI")
                        )

                ));
    }
```

and postDto and Response Code is here

```
public class DogDto {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor

    public static class Post {
        @NotBlank
        private String dogName;

        @NotNull
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date dogBirthDate;

        @NotNull
        private Dog.DogSpecies dogSpecies;

        @NotNull
        private int dogWeight;

        private String dogDescription;
    }

@AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter

    public static class Response {
        private long dogId;
        private String dogName;
        private String dogBirthDate;
        private Dog.DogSpecies dogSpecies;
        private int dogWeight;
        private String dogDescription;
   }
}
```

and controller's @PostMapping Code is here

```
  @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity postDog (@Valid @RequestBody DogDto.Post post, Principal principal){
        Dog creatingDog = dogMapper.dogPostDtoToDog(post);

        Dog createdDog = compositeService.createDog(creatingDog, principal.getName());
        DogDto.Response response = dogMapper.dogToDogResponse(createdDog);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and Entity's Code is here

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dogId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String dogName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private Date dogBirthDate;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private DogSpecies dogSpecies = DogSpecies.기타;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private int dogWeight;

    @Column
    private String dogDescription;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private Member member;
  }
```

I used @JsonFormat annotation at dogDto.Post

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 private String dogBirthDate;
```

and used too @DateTimeFormat annotation

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dogBirthDate;
```

but there are not passed test code too.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: try `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` on the `Date` object, also i do recommend that you use `LocalDate` instead of the old `Date` object

Comment: `new Date(2022-01-01)` is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Which of the two bundled classes did you mean by `Date`? `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For a date-only value, use `java.time.LocalDate`. Support for *java.time* is mandatory in JDBC 4.2 and later.

Comment: I used java.util.Date. 
and I tried LocalDate Type on dogBirthDate's field. That was too passed on postman but also failed on test code.
how can I coding on test code where stub dogDto.Post post (dogBirthDate) ?